# What is the difference between 'proxy_pass url' and 'proxy_pass upstream' in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, aws-lambda

**Ex1)**

```
    upstream uptest {
        server <some_lambda_id>.lambda-url.ap-northeast-2.on.aws:443;
        keepalive 100;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        #access_log off;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/uptest_acc.log  main;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/uptest_err.log error;

        server_name  <test_domain>;

        location / {
            proxy_pass https://uptest;
        }
    }
```

Ex1 is not work (403 forbidden and body response : {"Message":null})

**Ex2)**

```
    server {
        listen 80;

        #access_log off;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/uptest_acc.log  main;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/uptest_err.log error;

        server_name  <test_domain>;

        location / {
            proxy_pass https://<some_lambda_id>.lambda-url.ap-northeast-2.on.aws; 
        }
    }
```

Ex2 is work

What is the difference between 'proxy_pass url' and 'proxy_pass upstream' in Nginx ?
How to fix 'Ex1' code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `proxy_pass` sets two headers to default values, one of which is:

```
proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header) for details.

The value of `$proxy_host` is taken from the `proxy_pass` statement and **not** the `upstream` `server` statement.

So, the main difference will be the value of the `Host` header in the upstream request. In your upstream example, it will be set to `uptest` instead of the correct host name of the upstream server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are save my time~